# Need some clarifications for the equals operator (==)

Tags: javascript

I am confused about the statement below about the equal comparison operator `==`

> If the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript converts the operands then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a number or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if possible; else if either operand is a string, the other operand is converted to a string if possible. If both operands are objects, then JavaScript compares internal references which are equal when operands refer to the same object in memory.

However both `alert(true == "true")` and `alert(false == "false")` returns **false**. Why is this so?

> If either operand is a number or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if possible

In what case does JavaScript converts true and "true" to a number? The previous example doesn't convert them to numbers.

I have more doubts when looking at these examples:

```
''        ==   '0'           // false
0         ==   ''            // true
0         ==   '0'           // true
false     ==   'false'       // false
false     ==   '0'           // true
```

- `''` is **false** and `'0'` is **true**, but why the output is **false**?
- `0` would be interpreted as **false**, and `''` is also **false**. Then it becomes **true**. I can understand this.
- Why does a `'0'` interpreted as **true** when `0` is **false**?
- Why is `false` interpreted as **false** and `'0'` interpreted as **true**?

Could someone explain in more detail how the `==` operator works?

Comment: Use `===` instead of `==` for exact equality. `===` will check both _type_ and _value_ for equality.

Comment: `true` gets converted to 1 and `false` gets converted to 0.

Comment: If iwant to get correct out put of == how I can  use this

Comment: "`''` is false and `'0'` is true, but why the output is false?" What kind of question is this?

Comment: mean Some one ask this Question to me .that why I ask this

Comment: Practically you're asking why `false == true` returns `false`...

Comment: but I just want to what is expacted out put ?  of == why browser calculated this

Answer (score 4):

```
=== // strict check. Will compare value and type

== // will check only value not type
```

So,

```
0         ==    ''            // true

0         ===   ''            // false
```

> The == operator will compare for equality after doing any necessary
>   type conversions. The === operator will not do the conversion, so if
>   two values are not the same type === will simply return false. It's
>   this case where === will be faster, and may return a different result
>   than ==. In all other cases performance will be the same.

[Does it matter which equals operator (== vs ===) I use in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

Answer (score 2):

Why true =="true" and false=="false" is false?

> If either operand is a number or a boolean, the operands are converted
>   to numbers if possible

the boolean true can be converted to one .

```
console.log(Number(true)); // 1
```

Lets convert the second argument

```
console.log(Number("true"));  // NaN . "True" cannot be converted to a number
```

so this evalutes to  `1==NaN` // false. NaN is crazy because its not even equal to itself NaN==NaN

Same is the case with `false =="false"`

All your other queries can be solved using the same deduction.
try expliclity converting your arguments based on the rules and check its Value in console.

eg.) `console.log(TYPE(arg)) // Type is either String or Number`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [javascript documentation](http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/jsgrpComparison.htm). You want to use === instead of ==

=== checks for value and type equality.

From the documentation:

> **Equality (==, !=)**
>
> If the types of the two expressions are different, attempt to convert
>   them to string, number, or Boolean.
>
> NaN is not equal to anything including itself.
>
> Negative zero equals positive zero.
>
> null equals both null and undefined.
>
> Values are considered equal if they are identical strings, numerically
>   equivalent numbers, the same object, identical Boolean values, or (if
>   different types) they can be coerced into one of these situations.
>
> Every other comparison is considered unequal.
>
> **Identity (===. !==)**
>
> These operators behave identically to the equality operators except no
>   type conversion is done, and the types must be the same to be
>   considered equal.